# Schema validation failed: Property declared as origin of linking objects property is not a link

Tags: ios, realm

I have two `RLMObject`s named `RCRealmUser` and `RCRealmLocation`. `RCRealmUser` has a one-to-one relationship defined on `RCRealmLocation` and `RCRealmLocation` has an inverse relation with the `RCRealmUser`. This is how I have defined these two:

**RCRealmUser.h**

```
@interface RCRealmUser : RLMObject

@property NSNumber <RLMInt> *userId;
@property NSString *username;
@property NSNumber <RLMInt> *countryCode;
@property NSNumber <RLMDouble> *phoneNumber;
@property NSString *fullName;
@property NSString *profileImageURL;
@property RCRealmLocation *location;

- (id)initWithMantleModel:(RCUserProfile *)user;

@end

RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(RCRealmUser)
```

**RCRealmUser.m**

```
@implementation RCRealmUser

+ (NSString *)primaryKey {
    return @"userId";
}

+ (NSArray *)indexedProperties {
    return @[@"fullName"];
}

+ (NSDictionary *)defaultPropertyValues {
    return @{@"countryCode": @91};
}

- (id)initWithMantleModel:(RCUserProfile *)user {
    self = [super init];
    if(!self) return nil;

    self.userId = user.userId;
    self.username = user.username;
    self.countryCode = user.countryCode;
    self.phoneNumber = user.phoneNumber;
    self.fullName = user.fullName;
    self.profileImageURL = user.profileImageURL.absoluteString;
    self.location = [[RCRealmLocation alloc] initWithMantleModel:user.location];

    return self;
}

@end
```

**RCRealmLocation.h**

```
@interface RCRealmLocation : RLMObject

@property (readonly) RLMLinkingObjects *userId;
@property NSNumber <RLMDouble> *latitute;
@property NSNumber <RLMDouble> *longitude;
@property NSDate *timestamp;
@property NSNumber <RLMInt> *accuracy;

- (id)initWithMantleModel:(RCLocation *)location;

@end

RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(RCRealmLocation)
```

**RCRealmLocation.m**

```
@implementation RCRealmLocation

+ (NSArray<NSString *> *)indexedProperties {
    return @[@"timestamp"];
}

+ (NSDictionary<NSString *,RLMPropertyDescriptor *> *)linkingObjectsProperties {
    return @{@"userId": [RLMPropertyDescriptor descriptorWithClass:RCRealmUser.class propertyName:@"userId"]};
}

- (id)initWithMantleModel:(RCLocation *)location {
    self = [super init];
    if(!self) return nil;

    self.latitute = location.latitute;
    self.longitude = location.longitude;
    self.timestamp = location.timestamp;
    self.accuracy = location.accuracy;

    return self;
}
```

Now when I try to insert into `RCRealmUser` I encounter an error

> 'RLMException', reason: 'Schema validation failed due to the following
>   errors:
>
> - Property 'userId' declared as origin of linking objects property 'userId' is not a link.'

Am I doing something wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Linking objects" properties must represent links (relationships).

In your case, you're saying that the `RCRealmLocation.userId` property should represent `RCRealmUser` objects that link to that location via its `userId` property. However, `RCRealmUser.userId` isn't a relationship to `RCRealmLocation` objects, it's an optional integer.

I *believe* what you want is a property on `RCRealmLocation` that refers to all `RCRealmUser`s linking to that location with its `locations` relationship. You can accomplishing this by changing your `RCRealmLocation.userId` property to this:

```
@property (readonly) RLMLinkingObjects *users;
```

and your `linkingObjectsProperties` implementation to this:

```
return @{@"users": [RLMPropertyDescriptor descriptorWithClass:RCRealmUser.class propertyName:@"location"]};
```

Read [Realm's docs on inverse relationships](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#inverse-relationships) for more information.

Comment: Thanks! I had initially used this approach but Realm Browser was confusing and not displaying any inverse relationship to the `RCRealmUser` object. When accessing the user from code, it worked!